# Hatcher exercise 0.21

Tags: algebraic-topology, solution-verification

> If $X$ is a connected Hausdorff space that is a finite number of 2 spheres, any two of which intersect in at most one point. Show that $X$ is homotopy equivalent to a wedge sum of $S^1$'s and $S^2$'s

Proof. Let the space $X=\bigcup_{i\in I}S_i$ where $S_i\cong S^2$ be given. Then for each $S_i$, let $P_i$ be a set of points in $S_i$ that intersects with other points and let $T_i$ be a tree whose vertex set is $P_i$. Then $\bigcup_{i\in I}P_i$ is a connected graph so let $T$ be a spanning tree. Then as tree is contractible, $X\simeq X/T\simeq \bigvee S^2$. Hence the space is homotopy equivalent to wedge of $S^2$.

MY question is where does $S^1$ come? I can't see why $S^1$ is needed here. Could you explain this?

Comment: Think about what happens when you have a loop of spheres, that is spheres $S_1,\ldots,S_n$ such that $|S_i\cap S_j|=1$ iff $|i-j|=1$ or $i=1$ and $j=n$.

Comment: @AlessandroCodenotti Oh, right. So the resulting space is not a wedge sum of $S^2$ but wedge sum of a quotient $S^2/Q_i$ where $Q_i$ is a finite points in $S^2$ which is homotopic equivalent to $S^2\vee S^1\cdots\vee S^1$